# How can I add space between code and comment?

Tags: neovim, nerdcommenter

I'm using [nerdcommenter](https://github.com/preservim/nerdcommenter) alongside neovim, and every time I comment out a block of code with `<leader>cc`, the code isn't really spaced out:

```rust
fn main() {
    //println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

I want to get an output of something like this:

```rust
fn main() {
    // println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

Is there a command or configuration that I'm missing out on? (I haven't configured nerdcommenter at all in my vimrc)

Comment: That option is in the [doc](https://github.com/preservim/nerdcommenter/blob/master/doc/nerdcommenter.txt#L761).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [plugin docs](https://github.com/preservim/nerdcommenter) : use `g:NERDSpaceDelims` configuration option

```
" Add spaces after comment delimiters by default
let g:NERDSpaceDelims = 1
```

Or for Neovim with Lua configuration :

```
vim.g.NERDSpaceDelims = 1
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was searching for.